# Deleting the text from within a tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is mainProgram():

```
def mainProgram():
    typedCountry = e.get()
    Country = typedCountry.lower()
    print 'Your country is: ' + typedCountry + '\n'
    if Country in bannedCountries:
        banned(typedCountry)
    if Country in cpBannedCountries:
        cpBanned(typedCountry)
    if Country in skrillBannedCountries:
        skrillBanned(typedCountry)
    if Country in bacsCountries:
        Bacs(typedCountry)
    if Country in sepaCountries:
        sepa(typedCountry)
    if Country in eftCountries:
        eft(typedCountry)
    if Country in ltdCountries:
        ltd(typedCountry)
    if Country in marketsCountries:
        markets(typedCountry)
```

I ask the user to enter a country in a box, I have several lists of different countries, and I check if the user input matches any of the countries in every list. If it does I run a separate function that prints a line.

This is the main tkinter code

```
master = Tk()
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

def clear_text():
        #WHAT TO ENTER HERE???

b = Button(master, text = "Search", bg="lightyellow", command = mainProgram)
b.pack()

c = Button(master, text="Quit", bg="orange",
          command=master.quit)
c.pack()
d = Button(master, text="Clear", bg="orange",
          command=clear_text)
d.pack()
mainloop()
```

Before this I have several lists of different countries, and a dozen or so functions that just print stuff for the user, it is not relevant here.

I use tkinter to create an input box where a user can type a country (input gets assigned to typedCountry) and three buttons: Search, Clear and Quit. Search runs the mainProgram() function and the returned function gets printed to the tkinter box. However since I do not know exactly where it's being printed, I don't know how to tell the Clear button to delete the contents of the text box without destroying it completely.

This is how it looks like when I search for say United States:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPCBm.jpg

Then I search for Austria:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/omJPV.jpg

As you can see, one is printed below the other one, but I need to clear them out of the box. Since I don't know where tkinter is printing this, I can't clear it no matter what I do.

Here is the main code if it helps

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import os


allCountries = ['afghanistan','aland','albania','algeria','american samoa','andorra',
'angola','anguilla','argentina','armenia','aruba','australia','austria','bahamas',
'bahrain','bangladesh','barbados','belarus','belgium','belize','benin','bermuda',
'bhutan','bolivia','bonaire','bosnia and herzegovina','botswana','brazil','brunei',
'bulgaria','burkina faso','burma','burundi','cambodia','cameroon','cape verde',
'cayman islands','central african republic','chad','colombia','comoros','congo',
'cook islands','costa rica','cote d\'ivoire','crimea','croatia','cuba','cyprus',
'czech republic','denmark','djibouti','dominican republic','ecuador','egypt',
'el salvador','equatorial guinea','eritrea','estonia','ethiopia','falkland islands (malvinas)',
'faroe islands','finland','france','gabon','gambia','germany','ghana','greece',
'greenland','grenada','guam','guatemala','guinea','guinea-bissau','guyana',
'haiti','hungary','iceland','india','iran','iraq','ireland','italy','jamaica',
'japan','jordan','kazakhstan','kenya','kiribati','kosovo','kuwait','kyrgyzstan',
'laos','latvia','lebanon','lesotho','liberia','libya','liechtenstein','lithuania',
'luxembourg','macao','macedonia','madagascar','malawi','malaysia','maldives',
'mali','malta','marshall islands','martinique','mauritania','mauritius','mayotte',
'mexico','micronesia','moldova','monaco','mongolia','montenegro','montserrat',
'morocco','mozambique','myanmar','namibia','nauru','nepal','netherlands','new zealand',
'nicaragua','niger','nigeria','north korea','northern mariana islands','norway',
'oman','pakistan','palau','panama','papua new guinea','paraguay','peru','philippines',
'poland','portugal','puerto rico','qatar','romania','russia','rwanda','saint helena',
'saint kitts and nevis','saint lucia','saint vincent and the grenadines','samoa',
'sao tome and principe','saudi arabia','senegal','serbia','seychelles','sierra leone',
'singapore','slovakia','slovenia','solomon islands','somalia','south africa','south korea',
'spain','sri lanka','sudan','suriname','swaziland','sweden','switzerland','syria',
'taiwan','tajikistan','tanzania','thailand','togo','tokelau','tonga','trinidad and tobago',
'tunisia','turkey','turkmenistan','turks and caicos islands','tuvalu','uganda','ukraine',
'united kingdom','united states','uruguay','uzbekistan','vanuatu','venezuela',
'virgin islands, u.s.','western sahara','yemen','zambia','zimbabwe','palestine'
]

bannedCountries = ['afghanistan','american samoa','belarus','brazil','burundi',
'central african republic','crimea','congo','cook islands','cote d\'ivoire','crimea','cuba',
'guam','iran','japan','liberia','libya','myanmar','new zealand','north korea',
'northern mariana islands','puerto rico','russia','singapore','somalia','south korea',
'sudan','south sudan','syria','tokelau','turkey','ukraine','united states','vanuatu','virgin islands',
'western sahara','zimbabwe', 'timor-leste']

cpBannedCountries = ['venezuela','united states','belarus','bosnia and herzegovina',
'burundi','cote d\'ivoire','cuba','iran','iraq','kosovo','lebanon','liberia',
'macedonia','montenegro','myanmar',
'nigeria','north korea','saint helena','somalia','sudan']

skrillBannedCountries = ['angola','barbados','benin','burkina faso','cape verde',
'comoros','djibouti','faroe islands','gambia','greenland','grenada','guyana','laos',
'liechtenstein','macao','martinique','mongolia','namibia','niger','palau','samoa',
'suriname','tajikistan','togo','trinidad and tobago','turkmenistan']

bacsCountries = ["united kingdom",'ireland']

eftCountries = ['australia']

sepaCountries = ['austria','belgium','bulgaria','croatia','cyprus','czech republic','check',
'denmark','estonia','finland','france','french guiana','germany','greece','gibraltar',
'hungary','iceland','guadeloupe'
'ireland','italy','latvia','liechtenstein','lithuania','luxembourg','malta',
'martinique','mayotte','monaco','netherlands','norway','poland','portugal',
'romania','slovakia','slovenia','spain','sweden','switzerland','united kingdom']

ltdCountries = ['austria','belgium','bulgaria','croatia','cyprus','czech republic',
'colombia','denmark','estonia','finland','france','germany','greece','hungary','ireland',
'italy','latvia','lithuania','luxembourg','malta','netherlands','poland','portugal',
'romania','slovakia','slovenia','spain','united kingdom']

marketsCountries = ['albania','algeria','andorra','angola','anguilla','armenia',
'aruba','bahamas','bangladesh','barbados','belize','benin','bermuda','bhutan',
'bonaire','bosnia','herzegovina','bosnia and herzegovina','botswana','brunei',
'burkina faso','burma','cambodia','cameroon','cape verde','cayman islands',
'chad','comoros','djibouti','equatorial guinea','eritrea','ethiopia','falkland islands (malvinas)',
'faroe islands','gabon','gambia','ghana','greenland','grenada','guinea','guinea-bissau',
'guyana','haiti','iceland','india','jamaica','jordan','kazakhstan','kenya',
'kiribati','kosovo','kyrgyzstan','laos','lesotho','liechtenstein','macao',
'macedonia','madagascar','malawi','malaysia','maldives','mali','marshall islands',
'mauritania','mauritius','micronesia','mongolia','morocco','mozambique','namibia',
'nauru','nepal','niger','nigeria','norway','pakistan','palau','papua new guinea',
'philippines','rwanda','saint helena','saint kitts and nevis','saint lucia','saint vincent and the grenadines',
'samoa','sao tome and principe','senegal','serbia','seychelles','sierra leone',
'solomon islands','sri lanka','suriname','swaziland','tajikistan','tanzania','togo',
'tonga','trinidad and tobago','tunisia','turkmenistan','turks and caicos islands','tuvalu',
'uganda','uzbekistan','yemen','zambia','palestine']

ibanCountries = [
'lebanon', 'albania','andorra','austria', 'azerbaijan','bahrain','belgium','bosnia and herzegovina',
'brazil','bulgaria','croatia','cyprus','czech republic','denmark', "estonia",'faroe islands',
'finland','france','french guiana','germany','gibraltar','greece','guadeloupe','guernsey','hungary',
'iceland','ireland','isle of man','israel','italy','jersey','jordan','kuwait','latvia','liechtenstein',
'lithuania','luxembourg','macedonia','malta','martinique','mauritania','mauritius','mayotte',
'moldova','monaco','montenegro','netherlands','norway','pakistan','poland','portugal',
'qatar','reunion','romania','san marino','saudi arabia','serbia','slovakia','slovenia','spain',
'sweden','switzerland','united kingdom','saint barthelemy','saint martin','saint pierre and miquelon',
'tunisia','united arab emirates','kosovo'
]

noLPOACountries = ['austria', 'belgium','bulgaria','croatia','cyprus', 'czech republic',
'denmark', "estonia",'finland','france','germany','greece','hungary','iceland','ireland',
'italy','latvia','liechtenstein','lithuania','luxembourg','malta','netherlands',
'norway','poland','portugal','romania','slovakia','slovenia','spain','sweden','switzerland']

max50cpCountries = ['france','germany','greece','italy']

zuluBannedCountries = ['italy']

idchecklistCountries =['kenya']

nonidchecklistCountries = ['jordan','kuwait','oman','qatar','saudi arabia',
'united arab emirates']





def banned(x):
    if 'kingdom' not in x:
        Label(master, text="""Clients from %s cannot apply for a live account with FXCM.""" % x).pack()
    else:
        return
def cpBanned(x):
    Label(master, text="""Clients from %s cannot use credit/debit cards.""" % x).pack()

def cpAllowed(x):
    Label(master, text="Clients from %s can deposit with credit cards." % x).pack()

def skrillBanned(x):
    Label(master, text="Clients from %s cannot use Skrill" % x).pack()

def Bacs(x):
    Label(master, text="""Clients from %s can use BACS if their bank account is located in
%s and both their bank account and their FXCM account is in GBP.\nClients from %s can
apply for a Spreadbetting account.""" % (x, x, x)).pack()

def sepa(x):
    Label(master, text="""Clients from %s can use SEPA if their bank account is located either in
%s or in another European country, and both their bank account and their FXCM account is in EUR.
Clients from %s can have a maximum leverage of 200:1.""" % (x, x, x)).pack()

def eft(x):
    Label(master, text="""Clients from %s can use EFT if their bank account is located in
%s, and both their bank account and their FXCM account is in AUD.\nClients in %s must open with FXCM AU""" % (x, x, x)).pack()

def ltd(x):
    Label(master, text="Clients from %s must open with FXCM LTD" % x).pack()

def markets(x):
    Label(master, text="Clients from %s must open with FXCM Markets" % x).pack()

def noLPOA(x):
    Label(master, text="""All traders (MMs, IBs, family members, etc.) domiciled
within %s and/or managing funds for residents of %s must be regulated.
Managers acquiring clients across %s must have the appropriate passport or license
to do so.""" % (x, x, x)).pack()

def iban(x):
    lbl['text'] = "IBAN is required for all wire withdrawals with a beneficiary bank account located in %s." % x

def max50cp(x):
    Label(master, text="Residents of %s are NOT eligible for the ATG 50K CP deposit maximum. " % x).pack()

def zulu(x):
    Label(master, text="Residents of %s cannot use ZuluTrader. " % x).pack()

def idchecklist(x):
    Label(master, text="""For applicants residing in %s who have difficulty
    submitting a valid proof of residence, we can accept the ID checklist
    as an alternative. In addition, these clients will only be required
    to submit one photo ID and P.O. box proof of residence with the ID
    Checklist in lieu of two photo IDs.
    """ % x).pack()

def nonidchecklist(x):
    Label(master, text="""For applicants from %s who have difficulty submitting
    a valid proof of residence and reside in Kuwait, they are not required to
    send in an ID checklist or extra ID when submitting a POR listing a P.O.
    Box as long as the city/state matches the application. If the city/ state
    does not match, the ID checklist is required to satisfy the account opening
    requirements
    """ % x).pack()

def notFound(x):
    Label(master, text="Country %s was not found, please try again" % x).pack()

def printAsterix():
    Label(master, text="*"*40).pack()


def mainProgram():
    typedCountry = e.get() # This is the text you may want to use later

    if not typedCountry:
        return
    lowerCountry = typedCountry.lower()
    upperCountry = typedCountry.title()

    if lowerCountry in bannedCountries: #banned countries
        banned(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry in cpBannedCountries:#cp banned countries
        cpBanned(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry in skrillBannedCountries: #skrill banned countries
        skrillBanned(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry not in cpBannedCountries and lowerCountry not in bannedCountries and lowerCountry in allCountries:
        cpAllowed(upperCountry) #cp allowed countries
    if lowerCountry in sepaCountries: #sepa allowed countries (EEA)
        sepa(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry in eftCountries: #eft allowed countries (AU)
        eft(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry in ltdCountries: #LTD required
        ltd(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry in marketsCountries: #markets required
        markets(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry in noLPOACountries: #lpoa not available
        noLPOA(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry in ibanCountries: #iban required
        iban(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry in max50cpCountries:
        max50cp(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry in zuluBannedCountries:
        zulu(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry in idchecklistCountries:
        idchecklist(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry in nonidchecklistCountries:
        nonidchecklist(upperCountry)
    if lowerCountry not in allCountries: #not found
        notFound(typedCountry)

    printAsterix()


master = Tk()
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

def clear_text():
        lbl.withdraw()

b = Button(master, text = "Search", bg="lightyellow", command = mainProgram)
b.pack()

c = Button(master, text="Quit", bg="orange",
          command=master.quit)
c.pack()
d = Button(master, text="Clear", bg="orange",
          command=clear_text)
d.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: *"Since I don't know where tkinter is printing this"* What do you mean you don't know where tkinter is printing this. Did you write this program or not? Also, you've included waaaaay too much code for the problem you've described. Can you please produce an MCVE following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You could put all your labels in a frame and either destroy and recreate the frame in clear or just destroy all the children of the frame.

Comment: @EthanField I edited the code already, removed all the irrelevant things. And when I say I don't know tkinter is creating this, I mean I don't know exactly in which section of the widget it's being printed. It's not the master tk() box, it's not any of the buttons, it's not the Label box, it's as if it's printing in some inaccessible code dimension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creates a label for every time a successful query is run, that is assigned no name, so you cannot unpack it specifically. The labels are also created inside of the `master` box, your main window, not inside of a frame, which is something you should consider. To unpack all previous labels from your window, you should use:

```
slaves = master.pack_slaves()
for s in slaves:
    s.pack_forget()
```

then repack on top what you need to keep.

```
e.pack()
b.pack()
c.pack()
d.pack()
```

for each one of your buttons. However, after you clear what is on the screen, the text entry box does not empty. So instead you could clear that also if you desired.

```
foo = StringVar()
e = Entry(master, textvariable=foo)
```

Then when clearing, add:

```
foo.set("")
```

Hope this helps! GL

Comment: you did it, absolutely beautiful solution and it worked perfectly. cheers

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to click the green tick to show everyone that your question has been answered!

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to justify left every label? Because justify=LEFT sometimes works but sometimes it doesn't

Comment: @JosephHarari `justify` only affects the text within the `Label` widget. If you need to align the `Label` widget specifically then you can use the two attributes of `.pack()` `side` and `anchor` to get the desired result.